# May I use iOS xcode4.6.3 to distribute app on apple store now?

Tags: ios4

Even though Xcode 5 available, I’d still like to use Xcode 4.6.3 at times to submit updates of my app.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which version of Xcode you are using, You can upoload apps on appstore. Only thing you should take care is , to follow Apple's coding standards.